# Why does renormalizability mean that "ultimately locality will have to be abandoned"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, scale-invariance

This is stated by Zinn-Justin in his paper [Quantum Field Theory: renormalization and the renormalization group](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/phbl.19960520727/abstract):

> Low energy physics does not depend on all
>   the details of the microscopic model because
>   some RG has an IR fixed point or at least a
>   low dimension fixed surface. **Of course at
>   this stage the next more fundamental theory
>   may still assume the form of a local quantum
>   field theory, but ultimately locality will have
>   to be abandoned.**

Where does the connection between the fact that low energy physics does not depend on all details of the microscopic model and that "ultimately locality will have to be abandoned" come from?

Comment: There is very little context provided in the question, and the paper is paywalled.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Zinn-Justin is saying that renormalizability of low energy physics implies that locality will ultimately have to be abandoned.  There's no logical reason to believe that.  He's referencing a widely held belief in the physics community that physics is no longer local when you zoom in to distance scales so short that quantum gravity effects bcome strong.

Answer (score -2):

The connection between the fact that low energy physics does not depend on all details of the microscopic model and that "ultimately locality will have to be abandoned" "comes from" the procedure of integrating out short-distance physics. It was explicitly pronounced by S. Weinberg [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAub_FDSA5g). Presence of higher derivative counter-terms means non locality, if you like.

However, I have [another opinion](http://www.aiscience.org/journal/paperInfo/pj?paperId=2156).

Comment: +1 for the question, but there is possibly a translation issue in,  "pronounced"   by Weinberg might be thought by many to be too strong a word. "Put forward" or "suggested" would be much better, imo, unless Weinberg has proof:)

Comment: @Countto10: S. Weinberg has proofs, of course. It is a "classical" thing nowadays. It is called a "Wilsonian point of view". Another passage about it is **here**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhQuy6EKW-E

Comment: You've misunderstood the question.  Weinberg is explaining why the low energy approximation is non-local.   The OP is asking why the thing being approximated might be non-local.